onAnimationComplete not firing in framer-motion
<motion.div
    onAnimationComplete={() => console.log("should fire sometime")}
    animate={{
       opacity: 1,
       scale: 1,
    }}
    transition={{
       delay: 0.5,
       duration: 1,
    }}
>

The function is never fired and the console log is not shown. I also tried with variants and initial, exit and animate, but it still doesn't work.
Also I tried onAnimationEnd.
What am I missing here?

Strange that it isn't working for you. I tried to replicate the issue in this example but it was working correctly.
